# Como nombrar una variable con un guion en c# dentro de un objeto?

Tags: c#, .net, rest

Debo enviar unos headers para hacer consumo de una api y para esto me creo un objeto para enviarlos, el problema es que uno de los nombres de estos header tiene guiones y c# no me lo permite, este es mi objeto

```
var parametros = new
{
     name = "qwer",
     X-RELATION-ID = "asdf",
     search = "alkjb15",
 };

string param= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parametros);
```

y envio params en el request

```
 public string EnviarPost(string url, string usuario, string contraseña, string method, string request = null, string header = null)
```

me salta error: el nombre 'RELATION' no existe en el contexto actual.
y la api necesita que vaya con ese nombre por que ya lo probe con postman y solo funciona si tiene el nombre exacto, como podria hacer para solucionarlo?

Comment: Los identificadores en C# no admiten el caracter `-`. Si incluyeras el código completo con que intentas realizar la petición sería más fácil ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Las reglas para nombrar identificadores (de variables, funciones, clases y demás) son simples:

- Deben comenzar por una letra o con barra baja (**_**).
- Pueden contener caracteres Unicode de letras, dígitos decimales y algunos otros.
- También puedes nombrarlos como palabras claves del lenguaje (`for`, `if`, `while`, `static`, `break`, etc.) si lo precedes de **@**. Por ejemplo: `int @for = 0;`

Dentro de los símbolos permitidos nunca se mencionan aquellos que tienen funciones en el lenguaje (por ejemplo `+ - * / % , & |`).

Puedes consultarlo [en la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/identifier-names).

Comment: pero a fuerza necesito enviar ese nombre con guiones, asi lo pide la api

Comment: Bueno. C# no lo admite. Creo que esto debería solucionar tu problema, dale un nombre que C# acepte y antes de la variable agrega: `[JsonProperty("X-RELATION-ID")]`. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/jsonpropertyname.htm